# jquery get all input from specific form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any ways to populate all of the input from certain form?
let say, some thing like this:

```
<form id="unique00">
  <input type="text" name="whatever" id="whatever" value="whatever" />
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" id="whatever" value="whatever" />
  </div>
  <table><tr><td>
    <input type="hidden" name="whatever" id="whatever" value="whatever" />
    <input type="submit" value="qweqsac" />
  </td></tr></table>
</form>
<form id="unique01">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="whatever" id="whatever" value="whatever" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" id="whatever" value="whatever" />
  </div>
  <table><tr><td>
    <input type="hidden" name="whatever" id="whatever" value="whatever" />
  </td></tr></table>
  <select>blah...</select>
  <input type="submit" value="qweqsac" />
</form>
etc forms... forms...
```

*note: each form might have a different amount of input and type and also different html structure

so is there any way to populate the input from certain form id? eg if i click submit button from certain form id, then jquery will populate for me all of the input within those form id.
currently what i'm doing is like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){ return validateForm($(this)) });
function validateForm(form){
var retVal = true;
var re;
$.each(form.serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
  var input = $('input[name='+field.name+']');
  field.value = $.trim(field.value);
  switch(field.name){
    case "name" :
        and another cases...
      }
    })
 }
```

that was work,
but in that case, i only get the field.name and field.value, and actually what i want is, i want a jquery object for each input element, so i can access their css, id, name, and even animate those input element

is there any way for this?

please let me know and thank you in advance!
AnD

Answer (score 212, accepted):

To iterate through all the inputs in a form you can do this:

```
$("form#formID :input").each(function(){
 var input = $(this); // This is the jquery object of the input, do what you will
});
```

This uses the jquery [:input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) to get ALL types of inputs, if you just want text you can do :

```
$("form#formID input[type=text]")//...
```

etc.

Comment: I think :input works for that but otherwise you could do: `$("form#formID input[type=text],form#formID select")`

Comment: Note typo in your first answer above.  $("from should be $("form

Comment: `$("form#formID :input").each` outputs `input` type, `select` type and even `button` type inputs. At least it does in my code.

Comment: @TARKUS `input` vs `:input`.  $(":input") selects all jQuery form elements.  $("input") selects input tags only.

Answer (score 30):

The below code helps to get the details of elements from the specific form with the form id,

```
$('#formId input, #formId select').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
);
```

The below code helps to get the details of elements from all the forms which are place in the loading page,

```
$('form input, form select').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
);
```

The below code helps to get the details of elements which are place in the loading page even when the element is not place inside the  tag,

```
$('input, select').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
);
```

**NOTE:** We add the more element tag name what we need in the object list like as below,

```
Example: to get name of attribute "textarea",

$('input, select, textarea').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
);
```

Comment: I am not getting value of text using this  input.val().. can you help me in that ?

Comment: My bad. Sory i was looking at wrong place for output.

Answer (score 3):

Use **HTML** Form "elements" attribute:

```
$.each($("form").elements, function(){ 
    console.log($(this));
    });
```

Now it's not necessary to provide such names as "input, textarea, select ..." etc.

Comment: Dooh!    --way too much info. Try a more quickerer way of seeing form info
$("form:input").each(function(index)
 {            console.log(index, this.type, this.id, this.name, this.value, this.placeholder ); 
 }
);

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("submit","form",function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        $form = $(this);
        $i = 0;
        $("form input[required],form select[required]").each(function(){
            if ($(this).val().trim() == ''){
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
                $i++;
            }else{
                $(this).css('border-color', '');    
            }               
        })
        if($i != 0) e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).on("change","input[required]",function(e){
        if ($(this).val().trim() == '')
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        else
            $(this).css('border-color', '');    
    });
    $(document).on("change","select[required]",function(e){
        if ($(this).val().trim() == '')
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        else
            $(this).css('border-color', '');
    });
```