# Send all Form Data in WordPress ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, wordpress

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );

function my_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        email:email
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Hi , I tried the ajax integration in wordpress. The above example is from codex of wordpress. I am not sure. How to send the form data in ajax.

Previously i tried like

```
var data = {
            action: 'my_action',
            email:email
        };
```

That above data only send the value to db and it save perfect, but i need to store all those value like for example 
Here is the form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label></label>
<input type="text" name="fname" value=""/>

</form>
```

I also tried to send all value like

```
var data= {
action: 'my_action',
email:email,
fname:fname
};
```

But it doesn't work. For individually email only send and enter properly in db. Is the way to send all value through ajax.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the whole code? also your action in functions.php that the ajax request has to call. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get the values of each input

```
var fname = $('input[name="fname"]').val();
```

if you only have a few inputs this can be done with a few of these statments but if you have loads and of different types you will need to loop through them. There are number of good post on here for doing that.

e.g. [jquery get all input from specific form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291005/jquery-get-all-input-from-specific-form)

Comment: Are you sure that you cant just send the whole form?