# jQuery how to take all multiple form data in one array?

Tags: jquery

I want to have all data of my forms in one array

```
$('#teamMedewerker :selected').each(function(i){
    var form = $("form#urenformulier" + i).serializeArray();
    $.each($(form), function(i, field){
        //console.log(field.name + " : " + field.value);
            array = field.value;
            console.log(array);
    });
});
```

I want this result but dont know how to get this.

```
Array (employee1(test,test,test), employee2(test1,test2,test3))
```

each form is an employee, there are multiple forms.

Comment: And why would you want that? Generally most people just want to serialize the form so they can send it.

Comment: I want to submit the array

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291005/jquery-get-all-input-from-specific-form

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you should use `map` instead of `each`

```
var arrayOfEmployees = $('#teamMedewerker :selected').map(function(i){
    return [$("form#urenformulier" + i).serializeArray()];
}).get();
```

Now if you want to iterate over this you can do

```
arrayOfEmployees.forEach(function(employee){
    employee.forEach(function(field){
         console.log(field.name, field.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: tried your code, on severals way but gives me errors; Uncaught TypeError: employee.forEach is not a function

Comment: @erwin, you are right, the array was flattened. Try with the updated code please.

Comment: This works, only how I get each medewerker in one array? The outcome of this is the same of the begin post ^^

Comment: @Erwin each element of the outer array `arrayOfEmployees` is an array containing the data of an employee. (*the variable `employee` is an array with the fields of that form*)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm understanding it right now!