# Jquery validate for same field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jquery validator plugin to validate inputs

liberary url : https://jqueryvalidation.org/

i have al form where input fieds are dynamically generated and each row input names are same

```
<tr>  <td><input type="text" class="form-control username" name="username"/></td> </tr>
```

when user click on add button then one more row will add

```
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control username" name="username"/></td>
</tr>
```

i have following validation

```
$validator = $("#myform").validate(
             {
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,

            }


        }
    }
    );
```

my problem is this code will validate only first row username not dynamically generated field name

before asking question i have researched lots of thread no use.

i ref many links but not helped me much

[jQuery Validate multiple fields with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033184/jquery-validate-multiple-fields-with-the-same-name)

[jquery get all input from specific form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291005/jquery-get-all-input-from-specific-form)

[jquery validate plugin on dynamic form inputs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561712/jquery-validate-plugin-on-dynamic-form-inputs-not-working)

[jQuery Validation plugin doesn't validate dynamically created form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022224/jquery-validation-plugin-doesnt-validate-dynamically-created-form-elements)

[jQuery - How to dynamically add a validation rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033910/jquery-how-to-dynamically-add-a-validation-rule)

Comment: I think you need to add the fields like: `$newField.rules('add', { required: true });` when you click add button. Like this describes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561712/jquery-validate-plugin-on-dynamic-form-inputs-not-working

Comment: @AtheistP3ace.thanks you mean in on add new row i have to call this .also $newField means

Comment: Yes every time you add a new row you need specifically add the rule to the field. `$newField` is just a variable holding the input field you just added in the row. This one -> `<input type="text" class="form-control username" name="username"/>` for each time you add it.

Comment: To be honest 3 out of 5 of those links answer your question. Specifically the last 3.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace.you are absultey right.my nad i have wasted 5 to 6 hours to fix this issue.but you saved finaly .thanks .one more is same issue forbootstrap modal form not triggering

Comment: If you create a new question for the modal issue I will try to help.

Comment: sure.thanks for te response

Comment: @AtheistP3ace. as per your suggestion i tried its working for new element.suppose if i have already input value and if clear input and click on submit then it will submit.validation not working